Source Generated Files Can't Use Namespaces In Unity
I'm trying to get a source generator working, but for some reason its failing to include the namespace it needs. The generated code looks like this:
using OwlTree; // namespace proxy factory is from
using System;

public class ProjectProxyFactory : ProxyFactory
{
    ...
}

I'm getting the error:

OwlTree.Generator\OwlTree.Generator.OwlTreeGenerator\ProjectProxyFactory.g.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OwlTree' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

as well a bunch of others that are similarly saying that types from the OwlTree namespace are missing.
I followed these instructions: https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.1/Documentation/Manual/roslyn-analyzers.html
And this is what my generator dll looks like in editor:

The cs files that contain everything in the OwlTree namespace are in my Assets folder, they aren't compiled into their own dll, and the source generator isn't in a separate assembly definition. The things I've found are:

Moving the OwlTree code into or out of an assembly definition doesn't change anything.

Moving types that are in the OwlTree namespace out of the namespace fixes the not found errors in the source generated code.

The source generator works properly in my editor's language server when open in the unity project (as well as in my test projects outside of unity), so it's only an issue with how the generator is working in unity.

I've tried auto-reference & validate reference selected and unselected for the generator dll, it doesn't change anything.

The unity project's csproj has my dll included as an analyzer, but it doesn't contain
<EnableSourceGenerators>true</EnableSourceGenerators>



This is the csproj file for the generator itself:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    <EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>true</EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>
    <IsRoslynComponent>true</IsRoslynComponent>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference ExcludeAssets="runtime" Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.3" PrivateAssets="all">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference ExcludeAssets="runtime" Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.3.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference ExcludeAssets="runtime" Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(OutputPath)\netstandard2.0\$(AssemblyName).dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


UPDATE:
I've since tried to create a test class for the generator to be applied to:
namespace OwlTree
{
    // will have a proxy generated by the source generator
    public class Test : NetworkObject
    {

    }
}

This will make OwlTree.Test appear in ProjectProxyFactory.g.cs, and this access of OwlTree doesn't cause the error. When I try to change other accesses to use OwlTree, such as OwlTree.ProxyFactory, it still causes not found error.
Again, the file that contains the proxy factory definition is no different from my test file, in that it's just a cs file in my Assets folder. This is very strange.

UPDATE:
This is the project structure of the assets folder:
> Assets
    > Framework
        > OwlTree
            > OwlTree source code
        > OwlTree.Generator
            > generator dll
    > test file with Test class shown above


UPDATE
I fixed the bug. The issue was that the generator was being applied to more than just the main project. There were 2 other projects the generator was added (I don't know what they are). Looking into more documentation, this is apparently intended behavior. As a result, empty proxy factories were being generated for projects that didn't include OwlTree.
My solution was to only generate a factory if there are classes for the factory to generator for. Then, I added defaults in the framework to handle a non-existent factory, which were previously handled by having an empty factory.

does it have an asmdef in it?

Under Select Platforms for Plugin have you tried to enable the ones you want the dll to be loaded for...?

@derHugo yes, this doesn't change the error. The tutorial I linked to says to, at a minimum, unselect "any platform", "editor", and "standalone". However, another tutorial I found made by a Unity employee who works on supporting source generators said to unselect everything. Both do not fix the errors.

@BugFixer The generator itself doesn't have an assembly definition. Since my post, I tried giving it one, and the generator stopped running all together.

Where should the OwnTree namespace be declared?

@shingo I put my file organization in an edit. Are namespaces declared in some specific way? From what I understand, once you wrap something in namespace Name { ... } it's accessible throughout the project.
